# Global variable between run and controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a script angularjs with this code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('App_example', ['duScroll'])
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $window) {

    var url = $window.location.href;
    if( url.indexOf("section1") != -1 ) {
        $rootScope.edition = "section1";
    } else {
        if(url.indexOf("section2") != -1) {
            $rootScope.edition = "section2";
        } else if(url.indexOf("section3") != -1) {
            $rootScope.edition = "section3";
        } else {
            $rootScope.edition = "section4";
        }
     }
     if(!history || !history.replaceState) {
         return;
     }
     $rootScope.$on('duScrollspy:becameActive', function($event, $element){
         //Automaticly update location
         var hash = $element.prop('hash');
         if (hash) {
             history.replaceState(null, null, hash+'_'+$rootScope.edition);
         }
     });
});
```

and this controller :

```
myApp.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$document', '$rootScope', function($scope,$window,$location,$document,$state,$rootScope) {

     var url = $window.location.href;
     if( url.indexOf("section1") == -1 ) {
        $rootScope.edition = "section1";
     } else {
        if(url.indexOf("section2") != -1) {
            $rootScope.edition = "section2";
        } else if(url.indexOf("section3") != -1) {
            $rootScope.edition = "section3";
        } else {
            $rootScope.edition = "section4";
        }
     }
});
```

But I have this flollowing error and I don't know why. How can I pass global variable between the run and the controller. It's for manipulate the url without reloading.

**TypeError: Cannot set property 'edition' of undefined**

Thanks.

Comment: You missed `$state` dependency in dependencies definition, so `$rootScope` is assigned to parameter `$state`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all dependencies to function in correct order, because you missed some (like `$state`)

```
myApp.controller('ImageController', 
   ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$window', '$location', '$document', '$state',  
   function ($rootScope, $scope, $window, $location, $document, $state) {
      // code 
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

The string elements into the Array must match the dependencies injected (as arguments) on the function itself:

```
myApp.controller('ImageController', 
['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$document', '$state', '$rootScope', 
function ($scope, $window, $location, $document, $state, $rootScope) { 
    ... 
}]);
```

And that is because you are using “annotated dependency injection”, i.e., you are explicitly naming the dependencies with strings before injecting them into the controller. That's a best practice to avoid problems with minification, as explained here: [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation)

That said, you could also fix the issue by passing the function directly, without annotating the dependencies, like this:

```
myApp.controller('ImageController', 
function ($scope, $window, $location, $document, $state, $rootScope) { 
    ... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line. Your array mentions 5 parameters, but your function takes 6. You forgot to add `$state` to the array. As your code sits now, it will assign `$rootScope` to the `$state` object, and `$rootScope` will be undefined.

```
myApp.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$document', '$rootScope', function($scope,$window,$location,$document,$state,$rootScope) {
```

Simply add `$state` into the array, and your code should work as intended.

```
myApp.controller('ImageController', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$document', '$state', '$rootScope', function($scope,$window,$location,$document,$state,$rootScope) {
```

Comment: Thanks but you're three to answer me the same thing :/ I will choose the first who respond sorry but thanks again for anwsering me so fast ^^